# R bslib change navbar color bootstrap version 5

Tags: r, bootstrap-4, sass, shiny, bootstrap-5

Why does changing the navbar color not work with BS version 4 and 5 in shiny (version 1.6.0.9022)?

Reproducible example:

app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

theme_test <- bs_theme(version = 5,
                       primary = "#d83e3e") %>%
bs_add_rules(sass::sass_file("custom.scss"))

ui <- navbarPage(title = "Test", theme = theme_test)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

custom.scss

```
.navbar { 
    background-color: $primary;
    color: $primary;
}
```

run

```
library(shiny)
runApp("FOLDERNAME")
```

Answer (score 2):

After fiddling around a bit, I found the correct css/sass:

```
.bg-light, .navbar-default {
    background-color: $primary !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth considering that the right class may change depending on the theme and other settings. For example, for getting this right with `sandstone`, I used the following:

```
theme = bslib::bs_theme(
      version = "5",
      preset = "sandstone", 
    ) %>%
      bslib::bs_add_rules(rules = "
.navbar.navbar-inverse {
   background-color: $dark !important;
}")
```